Is it possible get a list of every external data used for a render?
Some renderers make it possible to access scene at render time using Python. This access allow you to make operations on the scene.
This gives the possibility to list every element needed for a specific render frame or animation.
My aim is to get a list of external data used for a specific render and not the whole blender file. In a blend file you could have a lot of scene, multiple viewlayers and multiples frames that are not requiring the same objects, textures, external datas etc...
Is there a way to list every element needed for a render ?
Thanks in advance ;)
